# Select Only Numbers From Varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server 2008 R2 I have some data in a varchar(12) column, it looks something like this:

```
Data:
%%1234
%1765
34566
123
%SDRMH
HJG434
```

I'd like to drop the '%' from all the rows that have it and also only select those which are numbers. I've already tried to use the ISNUMERIC() function, but it looks like that leaves the % in the rows.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of REPLACE and ISNUMERIC to achieve the result set you want:

```
SELECT REPLACE(columnName,'%','') FROM tableName
WHERE ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(columnName,'%','')) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `REPLACE` function to strip out all the % instances

```
SELECT REPLACE(column_name,'%','');
GO
```

Comment: he would still get values like 'SDRMH' and that's not what he wants

Answer (score 1):

This function would be expensive to use, but it could help you create / populate a new column properly typed as an int (for example):

```
create function [dbo].[is_int]
    (   @value as varchar(max)  )
returns int
as
begin
declare @return int
set @return = 5
while len(@value) > 0
begin
    if left(@value,1) in('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')
        begin
            set @value = right(@value, len(@value)-1)
            set @return = 1
        end
    else
        begin
            set @return = 0
            set @value = ''
        end
end
return @return
end
```

or you could modify it to return the integers themselves, instead of a true/false (1/0).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
SELECT REPLACE(column,'%','') WHERE ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(column,'%','')) = 1
```